# Cannot pass data from Controller to View using ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I set ViewBag in my Controller constructor and use it in _Layout.cshtml. This is what I have done many times in ASP.NET MVC (.NET Framework). The same code is not working in my new .NET6 ASP.NET Core application.

```
public HomeController(ILoggerFactory logger)
{
    CurrentUser = GetCurrentUser();
    ViewBag.CurrentUser = CurrentUser;
}
```

In _Layout.cshtml I have below code

```
</head>
@{
    AppUser _curUser = ViewBag.CurrentUser;
    // _curUser is null here!!
}
<body>
```

I also tried using `ViewData` but the same problem. I have done this many times in all my MVC web applications and I'm wondering why it's not working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ViewData` and `ViewBag` refer to the same underlying `ViewData` collection. Actually life of the `ViewData` or the `ViewBag` lies only during the current request.

I suppose that in your case result might be depending on the dependency injection used in your application.

For additional information see [Pass data to views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#pass-data-to-views)

Comment: I used a simple string data and still not working if I set ViewBag inside constructor. If I set ViewBag in my Index.cshtml, it works. Do you see any difference between setting ViewBag in controller's constructor compare to setting it in Index action ?

Comment: @FLICKER: If you set some value of the `ViewBag` inside a constructor it will be `null` when another action method is called. Therefore, it is necessary to set a value before calling the `View()` method that renders that view.

Comment: I was under impression that it should work. Seems I have to do as you instructed. Thank you.